# Pass the parameter from the VF page to command button action

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the VF Page and through a custom button I am passing the parameter To the VF  URL as `https://abc--c.cs41.visual.force.com/apex/Send_Env_Email?OppId=00655D0Z8` I want to reterive this within the same page so I can pass it in the commadButton so call the other controller method

```
<apex:page  controller="test_Controller1">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
         <h1>Send a Signing Request via Email</h1>
         <p>This form will send a DocuSign signing request. 
         Are you sure you want to send it?</p> 
         <p><apex:commandButton action="{!send}" onclick="clicked();" rerender="dssdk_output" value="Send!" /></p>
      </apex:pageBlock>  
  </apex:form>
```

Because the `send()` within  `test_Controller1` is looking for the input parameter `Public void send(set<id> oppIds)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value you can do something like with this symbol $ before your target. 
Can you show your class controller?